# Why do MIPS operations on unsigned numbers give signed results?

Tags: mips, unsigned

When I try working on unsigned integers in MIPS, the result of every operation I do remains signed (that is, the integers are all in 2's complement), even though every operation I perform is an unsigned one: `addu`, `multu` and so fourth...

When I print numbers in the range `[2^31, 2^32 - 1]` I get their 'overflowed' negative value as if they were signed (I guess they are).

Though, when I try something like this:

```
li $v0, 1
li $a0, 2147483648                # or any bigger number
syscall
```

the printed number is always `2147483647 (2^31 - 1)`

I'm confused... What am I missing?

PS : I haven't included my code as it isn't very readable (such is assembly code) and putting aside this problem,
seems to be working fine. If anyone feels it is necessary I shall include it right away!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture):

> The MIPS32 Instruction Set states that the word unsigned as part of Add and Subtract instructions, is a misnomer. **The difference between signed and unsigned versions of commands is not a sign extension (or lack thereof) of the operands, but controls whether a trap is executed on overflow (e.g. Add) or an overflow is ignored (Add unsigned)**. An immediate operand CONST to these instructions is always sign-extended.

From the [MIPS Instruction Reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html):

> ALL arithmetic immediate values are sign-extended [...] The only difference between signed and unsigned instructions is that signed instructions can generate an overflow exception and unsigned instructions can not.

Comment: I was looking all over the net for an answer... anywhere but the obvious. thanks!

Comment: Then why do they use the terminology "signed and unsigned" instead of something like "checked and unchecked"?

Comment: It's a misnomer. Read the first quote.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the real problem is the syscall that you are using to print numbers.  It appears to and to always interpret what you pass as signed, and to possibly to bound as as well.