# can someone help me to do unsigned subtraction in hex

Tags: hex, unsigned, subtraction

5ED4-07A4
doing this normally i just get 5730, im wondering if there is a special way to do this with unsigned numbers? i know that means they cant be negative but not sure how to implement that.

Comment: Unsigned numbers CANNOT be negative. Please clarify, add some context: are you trying to do this by hand, with calculator, programming?

Comment: ok yeah thats what i meant, CANT be negative. im just trying to do it by hand

Comment: What do you mean "by hand"?  Unsigned arithmetic isn't usually a thing outside of computers, and any answer is going to depend on the maximum integer value and other details of the system you're working in.

Comment: If you're doing the math *by hand*, then your question is off-topic here. This site is for programming related questions. If you're trying to do it in code, explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code in the form of a [mcve], and ask a specific question about that code, and we'll try to help.

Comment: ok sorry about that. just doing it by hand to visualize it better so i understand. im am trying to understand it for mips programming.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MIPS, but [this may be relevant for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976793/why-do-mips-operations-on-unsigned-numbers-give-signed-results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, if you are doing that by hand, the best way to do substractions, as far a I know, is the primary school way (of course in hex):

```
 000
 5ED4
-07A4
 ----
 5730
```